# Xylene leaves a stain after evaporating?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm using xylene to clean a sacrificial polymer layer off of a PMGI surface in a ventilated hood.

For some reason, when xylene dries naturally from the surface there is a liquid stain that can be seen visibly on the PMGI. The stain can be removed by spraying with more xylene and then blowing it off with N2.

This stain will happen even if I apply xylene to a clean PMGI surface that has never been coated in the sacrificial layer so it isn't just incomplete cleaning. It seems like a contaminant is coming from the xylene.

My xylene is specified to have only 5 ppm of residue after evaporation. Is this enough to leave a visible stain after a thin layer evaporates?

Comment: Have you tried a drop of xylene on clean glass? That would show whether it's the solvent or something in the substrate leaving the stain.